# apt-get not recognizing newest version of python-matplotlib

Tags: upgrade, python, matplotlib

I'm trying to update matplotlib from an old to the newest version 2.0.2.

Through apt-get I am told matplotlib is already the newest version "1.5.1"

Do I have to update the repository or something like that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28111323/how-can-i-install-the-latest-versions-of-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-ipython-pandas-o

Answer (score 0):

In the end, trying to update repositories and so on, I tried awhat someone suggested in another thread, using pip.  I don't know what pip is, but it worked very well and easily.

Comment: PIP = python index [of] packages

it's updating via python repos; rather than ubuntu.